# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map bytes for committing reserved memory

Tags: java, linux, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory

I am running a download server in AWS t2.micro instance & I have configured max heap of 512 MB & min heap of 256 MB for my java process. I am performing a migration kind of process in a single thread which downloads files (Sizes < 50MB)from google drive. But when I run it, I get the following error

```
error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12) # # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue. # Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 33558528 bytes for committing reserved memory.
```

Here is extracts from hs_err_pid13942.log

VM Arguments:

```
jvm_args: -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=32m -XX:MaxPermSize=64m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

Here is my meminfo

```
/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:        1016324 kB
MemFree:           58792 kB
Buffers:             344 kB
Cached:            15984 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           899232 kB
Inactive:          14664 kB
Active(anon):     897692 kB
Inactive(anon):      332 kB
Active(file):       1540 kB
Inactive(file):    14332 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                72 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        897608 kB
Mapped:             6284 kB
Shmem:               416 kB
Slab:              22276 kB
SReclaimable:      10960 kB
SUnreclaim:        11316 kB
KernelStack:        1408 kB
PageTables:         7460 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:      508160 kB
Committed_AS:     881084 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:        4664 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359727628 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:    591872 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       28672 kB
DirectMap2M:     1150976 kB
```

Here is the cpu info

```
/proc/cpuinfo:
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 63
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2676 v3 @ 2.40GHz
stepping        : 2
microcode       : 0x25
cpu MHz         : 2394.552
cache size      : 30720 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 1
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 1
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm xsaveopt fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid
bogomips        : 4789.10
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

Memory: 4k page, physical 1016324k(58792k free), swap 0k(0k free)
```

I can see there is 58 MB free & also i see sufficient memory free while monitoring with 'free -h' command in the instance. So I don't understand why did this error occur in the first place. Can someone explain to me the reason & also what am i doing wrong wrt to memory configuration ?

Comment: Interesting, I do have the very same situation. Even excellent talks like this did not help me: https://vimeo.com/364039638. Setting Xms and Xmx to the same value helps to fix the mem a little more and makes a little bit more predictable system.

Just guessing: Maybe the amount for increasing the heap and to mem map the files for Linux collides here. Maybe /meminfo was just not taken at that exact point in time. (which is very hard to achieve)